# How to decide whether a Kernel Density Estimate is good?

Tags: scikit-learn, density-function, kernel-smoothing

Consider [this samples set](https://bpaste.net/show/76dcbb5bd578), feel free to look at it by using your own favourite tools (e.g. R, Python, whatever other stats tools).

The problem is that I lack experience in deciding whether any of these PDF estimations are reasonable, or whether there is even a possibly better estimation.

Thus the question in the title:

- **Q1:** how to decide whether a KDE is good?

From this question raises another sub question:

- **Q2:** is it a problem that my tails aren't touching 0 on the Y axis?

Using the data above, here are various KDEs that I made using 3 different kernels and bandwidths as follows:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And the code that generated those plots (replace *PATH/TO/SAMPLES/FILE* by the correct path to the samples set):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

fle = 'PATH/TO/SAMPLES/FILE'
with open(fle, 'r') as f:
    X = [float(s) for s in f.read().splitlines()]
X.sort()

X_np = np.array(X)
X_np = X_np.reshape(-1,1)

# kernel density estimations
kernel='epanechnikov'
bw=0.001
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='gaussian'
bw=0.001
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='tophat'
bw=0.001
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()


kernel='epanechnikov'
bw=0.01
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='gaussian'
bw=0.01
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='tophat'
bw=0.01
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()


kernel='epanechnikov'
bw=0.05
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='gaussian'
bw=0.05
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='tophat'
bw=0.05
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()


kernel='epanechnikov'
bw=0.09
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='gaussian'
bw=0.09
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

kernel='tophat'
bw=0.09
kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=bw).fit(X_np)
plt.plot(X_np, np.exp(kde.score_samples(X_np)), label='%s, bw=%s' % (kernel, bw))
plt.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By eye, I'd say something between plots 2 and 3 would be good, but this is based on prior beliefs about what distributions tend to look like for data that I've encountered. For example, #1 looks far too spiky. But, it's certainly possible to draw data from a distribution that's actually like that, and the spiky estimate would then be the correct choice. I just believe a priori that it's probably not spiky. But in fact, among all possible distributions, the one with highest likelihood is the empirical distribution, which is a set of delta functions over the data points. Of course that doesn't seem reasonable, and the whole point of using a KDE is to impose something like a smoothness prior.

Instead of eyeballing it, it's often better to pick the kernel bandwidth using a principled approach. There are some simple formulas based on distributional assumptions. I prefer cross validation (this should be straightforward since you're using scikit-learn). Fit the KDE on the training set, evaluate the likelihood on the test set. Choose the bandwidth that maximizes the cross validated likelihood.

Regarding question 2, the tails will touch zero if you extend the range over which you evaluate the density.

Comment: While not very related (but I find it interesting) is your comment on the *set of delta functions*: do you mean the Dirac delta functions? If so, I assume  the PDF that maximizes the likelihood would look like a comb (many tiny spikes) such that the length of each comb is $1/500$ (since I have $500$ data points) -- is this right?

Comment: After thinking about the cross-validation method for a while, I wonder, how can you exactly test the fitness of the estimated PDF by using the testing set? I see that I estimate the PDF by the training set (easy), but then, should I use the testing set to estimate the PDF of the testing set, and then compare the difference between the PDF of the training against the PDF of the testing? Or, how exactly?

Comment: Yes, weighted Dirac delta functions, each w/ integral 1/n (which incidentally is equivalent to the limit of kde w/ gaussian kernel as kernel width goes to 0). Just mentioned empirical distribution to say that training set likelihood isn't a good criterion for choosing kernel width

Comment: Re:cross validation...Fit kde on the training set. Measure summed log probability of the test points using that kde. Sum over CV folds. Repeat for different kernel widths. Choose width that maximizes log probability of test set.

Comment: How to measure summed log probability of test points? I guess "summed log" could be replaced by "multiplied" because multiplication becomes summation in log space, but you favoured summation here cause such multiplications can become really really tiny (too many rounding errors)? But how to measure such probabilities (let alone multiplying them or summing them in log space) -- thanks!

Comment: Yes exactly right about the log. In your code,  numpy.sum(kde.score_samples(xtest)) should give sum of log probabilities of test points (for test set vector xtest)

Comment: But these points are only densities (not probabilities). I think we can say that the density at point $x$ for this specific source of samples $y$ is $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$. If we multiply it by $p_Y(y)$ and then divide it by $f_X(x)$, only then it will be a probability of $\Pr(Y=y|X=x)$. But since $P_Y(y)$ and $f_X(x)$ are identical for all distributions, we can omit them I guess since monotonically it will lead to the same maxima? Is this why you are suggesting to treat this density as a probability?

Comment: Apologies, I was using incorrect terminology in the previous 2 comments. As you pointed out, they're densities and not probabilities bc we're talking about a continuous distribution. What we want to maximize is log likelihood of the kde given the test set, which is calculated as sum of log of kde evaluated at the test points.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much. Highly appreciate your help.